# trying to extract values from a shortcode using a worpdress native function. No dice

Tags: php, wordpress, extract, shortcode

I'm trying to figure out how to extract value-attributes pairs from a shortcode. Clearly I only care for the attributes that are there and that the user has entered.

I have it nailed with regex, but I'm told (by a laconic user of SO) that I should be able to do that with a native wordpress function, `shortcode_atts`, which is described [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts).

However for the life of me I cannot get it to return the values.

First off, it is odd to me that I should feed to this function the default values every time I need to use it. It is clearly not designed to extract the values in the first place. But whatever.

```
$defaults_atts = array(
                    'width'    => 640,
                    'height'   => 360,
                    'mp4'   => '',
                    'autoplay' => '',
                    'poster'   => '',
                    'src'      => '',
                    'loop'     => '',
                    'preload'  => 'metadata',
                    'webm'   => ''
            );
            $rest = substr($post->post_content, 0, -8);  // remove the closing [/video]
            $videoattr = shortcode_atts( $defaults_atts , $rest, 'video' );
```

notice that I'm using `$post->post_content` since all the post contains is the shortcode for a video. I only remove the closing shortcode tag I don't need. (Before you tell that's wrong, I tried not doing that and nothing changes.)
The shortcode in `post_content` typically contains attributes ranging from width and height to the source files, mp4 or webm. In a simple case, it may look like this:

```
[video width="1080" height="1920" webm="http://path/file.webm" autoplay="true"][/video]
```

Now, when I test the above with `print_r($videoattr)` all I get is the array with the default values.

What am I doing wrong??

Here's more testing which fails, following suggestion:

first I modify the my_shortcode function:

```
function my_shortcode( $atts=array(), $content=null) {
        $attribute = shortcode_atts( array(
                    'width'    => '640',
                    'height'   => '360',
                    'mp4'   => '',
                    'autoplay' => '',
                    'poster'   => '',
                    'src'      => '',
                    'loop'     => '',
                    'preload'  => 'metadata',
                    'webm'   => '',
            ), $atts);

    /*echo '<pre>', print_r($attribute, 1),'</pre>';*/
    echo '<pre>', print_r($atts, 1),'</pre>';
    /*echo '<pre>', print_r($content, 1),'</pre>';*/
}
```

then I call it using... what I have, which is post_content.

```
my_shortcode($post->post_content);
```

This returns, as $atts, the same shortcode I originally fed to the function.

I understand that according to the function above, I should have fed an array of attributes, which is exactly what I don't have.

Comment: can you post your whole code shortcode function? it doesn't look right

Comment: ...there's nothing else after this. All it's got before is a global call to `$post` and `$posts`. I'm waiting to implement more the moment I get the right values in `print_r`. This is a function being called during the loop which I use to retrieve the url of the posted video to use it in the home page in a fancybox. (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 2):

the attributes that are pass on the shortcode are stored in $atts variable, or the first argument on your function

to give you an idea, here's how it works,

lets say you have a shortcode like this

`[mys hello="world" print="no"]Content[/mys]`

and your php function looks like this,

```
function my_shortcode( $atts=array(), $content=null) {
    $attribute = shortcode_atts( array(
        'that' => 'is',
        'this' => 'no',
    ), $atts);
    echo '<pre>', print_r($attribute, 1),'</pre>';
    echo '<pre>', print_r($atts, 1),'</pre>';
    echo '<pre>', print_r($content, 1),'</pre>';
}
```

the output will be

```
#echo '<pre>', print_r($attribute, 1),'</pre>';
Array (
    [that] => is
    [this] => no
)
#echo '<pre>', print_r($atts, 1),'</pre>';
Array (
    [hello] => world
    [print] => no
)
#echo '<pre>', print_r($content, 1),'</pre>';
Content
```

`$attribute` is the default attributes pass into the function,

`$atts` - attributes assigned and found on the shortcode tag, it will override the defaults if key matches,

`$content` - content that are enclosed inside a shortcode,

Comment: I don't why this is so hard for me to understand, but... can `$atts` be the full shortcode, including the brackets? 'cause otherwise if I have to extract the attributes myself in some other way I don't need this function :)

Comment: not sure whats so hard about it, but based on your shortcode, you can easily extract its value, by ```$atts['width']``` the value of the width -```$atts['height']``` value of the height - ```$atts['webm']``` value of webm ```$atts['autoplay']``` value of auto play

Comment: ...when I try doing this I get the default values, not the values entered by the user in the shortcode. That's the whole conundrum <= difficult word to feel less stupid

Comment: if I change your function "my_shortcode" by feeding to `$attribute` the default array of values for video, and then call such function with `my_shortcode($post->post_content)`, it will print the default values given in attribute AND the full shortcode with the attributes entered by the user. it will NOT print the attributes entered by the user as an array I can extract,

Comment: post your whole shortcode function and the shortcode you are testing then I might be able to help you, I don't even know if you are doing the right thing like passing the $atts argument on your function

Comment: the ```$attribues``` are defaults, its the $atts that you pass as first argument on your function that stores the attributes define on the shortcode tag

Comment: I think the problem lays here: I have the shortcode in the form of post_content. It includes bracket and all. **I don't have an array of attributes.** The array of attributes is what I need here!

Comment: OK, I edited my answer adding the test with your function. Please keep in mind this: my purpose is to go from this: `[video width="1080" height="1920" webm="http://path/file.webm" autoplay="true"][/video]` to this: `Array( width=>1080, height=>1920,webm=>"http://path/file.webm" autoplay=>"true");`

Comment: Please read https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API, shortcode functions aren't design as a callable function, it should be pass to ```add_shortcode``` function.. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but it looks like you shouldn't be doing it with shortcode

Comment: I looked at Shortcode_API. I cannot find the answer to my problem there. I don't think I should use `add_shortcode` because I am not trying to *create* a shortcode, but to *extract* its values. In fact I'm not "doing shortcode" at all. Wordpress has put that shortcode there, I just need to use its values. I don't understand what's so strange about that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was in fact the function `shortcode_parse_atts` described here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_parse_atts/